# Java overriding abstract method design strategy

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, overriding

I have such classes:

```
abstract class Person{void toDrink(Liquid l);}

class Liquid{}
class Alcohol extend Liquid{}
class Milk extends Liquid{}


class Adult extends Person{void toDrink(Liquid l){}}
class Child extends Person{void toDrink(Liquid l){}}
```

I want Child and Adult not to take Liquid as args but Milk and Alcohol respectively, but I have to override abstract method with exactly Liquid argument. So when I write

```
Person child = new Child();
child.toDrink(new Alcohol());
```

child can take Alcohol as argument to drink.
 I can solve this problem using Exceptions or if(), but I ask you to advice me a better design for these relations. I want it when I pass a wrong argument to the method toDrink()  (alcohol to child or milk to adult) my IDE underline it as a mistake and compilation error when I try to run it.

Comment: a bit off topic but: if `toString()` turns an object into a String what does `toDrink()` do?

Comment: First: welcome to StackOverflow. For your question: if you want the IDE to handle this abstraction is not needed because then no extension will be possible. You use only `abstract class` if you do not know anything about this at compile time.

Comment: you can use instanceof here to check which instance it actually points to.

Comment: Not an answer as such, only a generic comment: you generally 'implement' (not override) abstract methods in child classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create like below ?

```
abstract class Person<T extends Liquid>{
    void toDrink(T l) {

    }
}
```

In the above code, you are binding the `toDrink()` method to accept a type which extends `Liquid`

```
class Adult<T extends Alcohol> extends Person<T>{

    void toDrink(T l){

    }
}

class Child<T extends Milk> extends Person<T>{
    void toDrink(T l){

    }
}
```

In the above code, you are binding the `toDrink()` of `Adult` and `Child` method to accept a type which extends `Alcohol` and `Milk` respectively.

Now, as per you expectation below code fails (with compilation error)

```
    Person<Milk> child = new Child<Milk>();
    child.toDrink(new Alcohol()); // error here
```

but this one works

```
    child.toDrink(new Milk());
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have to explicitly write the type of acceptable drink     when creating Person. Is there any way to elude it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use generics to solve this:

i would suggest to create a class between `Liquid` and `Milk`:

```
public abstract class NonAlcoholicLiquid extends Liquid {}
public class Milk extends NonAlcoholicLiquid {}
```

and modify your Person classes respectivly

```
public abstract class Person<Drink extends Liquid> {
    void doDrink(Drink drink) {

    }
}


public class Adult<Drink extends Liquid> extends Person<Drink> {
    void doDrink(Drink drink){

    }
}

public class Child<Drink extends NonAlcoholicLiquid> extends Person<Drink> {
    void doDrink(Drink drink){

    }
}
```

This way children may only drink non alcoholic liquids while adults are still allowed to drink milk ;)

Update:

According to your comment we can skip generics for the moment:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public abstract void doDrink(Liquid drink);
}


public class Adult extends Person {
    void doDrink(Liquid drink) {
        if(!(drink instanceof Alcohol)) {
            throw new InvalidDrinkException("Adults may only drink Alcohol");
        }
        // do the adult's drinking stuff
    }
}

public class Child extends Person {
    void doDrink(Liquid drink){
        if(!(drink instanceof Milk)) {
            throw new InvalidDrinkException("Children may only drink Milk");
        }
        // do the child's drinking stuff
    }
}
```

But your approach has a flaw in thinking: When a child grows up the instance is the same but the class would have to change...

Comment: Thank you! But adults are not allowed to drink milk)) And the real problem is when we instantiate Child through Person reference, we could apply to it method toDrink with alcohol.  Person child = new Child(); child.toDrink(new Alcohol) - isn't a compilation mistake, but ClassCasstException. And we could have to work with objects via their superclass references.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, we can solve this problem using "if" and exceptions. I think it's not the best design so I posted this question. But may be there is no appropriate answers, though your variants with generics are rather good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`I want Child and Adult not to take Liquid as args but Milk and Alcohol respectively` means Adult drinks only Alcohol and Child only Milk. So you can use generics with the type of Liquid that each Person sub-type drinks as type parameter.

```
abstract class Person<L extends Liquid> {
 void toDrink(L l) {
   //implementation here.
 }
}

class Liquid{}
class Alcohol extend Liquid{}
class Milk extends Liquid{}

 class Adult extends Person<Alcohol>{
    // You don't necessarily need to override the toDrink method.
 }

 class Child extends Person<Milk>{ }
```

You don't need to override the `toDrink()` method in each sub-class. You could have only one implementation in the abstract Person class.

Comment: It doesn't work if we write: Person p = new Child(); p.toDrink(new Alcohol());  It works only when we create reference of type Child

Comment: @ka4eli If you want to declare `p` as `Person`, then at compile time you can't make sure that its `toDrink(l)` method will take the right argument. The reason is that the compiler does not know what type of `Person` `p` is.

Comment: @ka4eli You can add a type check of the argument in the implementation of the `toDrink(l)` methods of `Adult` and `Person`. But then you would just throw a `RuntimeException` if `l` was of the wrong type. You get the same result (a ClassCastException) with my approach. The difference is that you don't have to write the type check code.